# When to choose association over query

Tags: api, rest, http

Let's say I am making a RESTful API with dogs and their owners. I have a dogs endpoint `/dogs/123` and owners endpoint `/owner/321`.

If I want to list owner's dogs, I can either GET `/owner/321/dogs` or `/dogs?owner_id=321`.

Which one is preferable in which situation? Should I support both these options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in this [best practices reference card](http://blog.octo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/RESTful-API-design-OCTO-Quick-Reference-Card-POSTER-2.4.pdf) :

> You should leverage the hierarchical nature of the URL to imply structure (aggregation or compositon)

you could choose :

```
GET /owners/321/dogs
```